# How do you find only properties that have both a getter and setter?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

C#, .NET 3.5

I am trying to get all of the properties of an object that have BOTH a getter and a setter for the instance.  The code I *thought* should work is

```
PropertyInfo[] infos = source.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
```

However, the results include a property that does not have a setter.  To give you a simple idea of my inheritance structure that might be affecting this (though I don't know how):

```
public interface IModel
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class BaseModel<TType> : IModel
{
    public virtual string Name { get { return "Foo"; } }

    public void ReflectionCopyTo(TType target)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] infos = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in infos)
            info.SetValue(target, info.GetValue(this, null), null);
    }
}

public class Child : BaseModel<Child>
{
    // I do nothing to override the Name property here
}
```

I end up with the following error when working with Name:

```
System.ArgumentException: Property set method not found.
```

EDIT: I would like to know why this does *not* work, as well as what I should be doing to not get the error.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Call [`GetGetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getgetmethod.aspx) and [`GetSetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getsetmethod.aspx) on the property - if both results are non-null, you're there :)

(The parameterless versions only return public methods; there's an overload with a boolean parameter to specify whether or not you also want non-public methods.)

Comment: But why doesn't the BindingFlags.SetProperty already doing that filtering? That's what I thought it was supposed to do.

Comment: @Matt: Because BindingFlags.SetProperty and BindingFlags.SetProperty are not used for look-up, they are used in other circumstances, Get Properties() method ignores those flags. Try without them you will get the same result.See supported flags: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx

Answer (score 42):

You can check the `PropertyInfo.CanRead` and `PropertyInfo.CanWrite` properties.

Comment: Note, though, that they'll return `true` even if the getter/setter is not `public`. These properties just check for the existence of the getter/setter.

Answer (score 39):

how about...

```
var qry = typeof(Foo).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite);
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supposed to work.

See definition of `GetProperties` on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332493(VS.71).aspx) for which is allowed:

The following `BindingFlags` filter flags can be used to define which nested types to include in the search:

```
* You must specify either BindingFlags.Instance or BindingFlags.Static in order to get a return.
* Specify BindingFlags.Public to include public properties in the search.
* Specify BindingFlags.NonPublic to include non-public properties (that is, private and protected members) in the search.
* Specify BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy to include static properties up the hierarchy.
```

Or you can see the definition of `GetProperty`/`SetProperty` in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(VS.71).aspx), which states that:

> GetProperty = Specifies that the value of the specified property
>   should be returned.
>
> SetProperty = Specifies that the value of the specified property
>   should be set. For COM properties, specifying this binding flag is
>   equivalent to specifying PutDispProperty and PutRefDispProperty.

Answer (score 0):

To make it a little more generic you can inherit from 'ObjectWithDefaultValues' and/or call obj.SetDefaultValues() extension method. Both are listed below.

Code:

```
public abstract class ObjectWithDefaultValues : object {

    public ObjectWithDefaultValues () : this(true){
    }

    public ObjectWithDefaultValues (bool setDefaultValues) {
        if (setDefaultValues)
            this.SetDefaultValues();    
    }
}

public static class ObjectExtensions {

    public static void SetDefaultValues(this object obj) {
        foreach (FieldInfo f in obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.SetField)) {
            foreach (Attribute attr in f.GetCustomAttributes(true)) {
                if (attr is DefaultValueAttribute) {
                    var dv = (DefaultValueAttribute)attr;
                    f.SetValue(obj, dv.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var p in obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.SetProperty)) {
            if (p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0) {
                foreach (Attribute attr in p.GetCustomAttributes(true)) {
                    if (attr is DefaultValueAttribute) {
                        var dv = (DefaultValueAttribute)attr;
                        p.SetValue(obj, dv.Value, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```